# If $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $\inf(A\cap B)\geq\max\{\inf A,\inf B\}. $

Tags: real-analysis

How would I go about proving the following statement:

If $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $B \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $\inf(A\cap B)\geq\max\{\inf A,\inf B\}. $

Comment: I changed each instance of \operatorname{inf}, \operatorname{sup}, and \operatorname{max} to \inf, \sup, and \max respectively.  These are already standard operatornames.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $A\cap B\subseteq A$.

Therefore every lower bound of $A$ is a lower bound of $A\cap B$.  (If something is true of every member of $A$ (namely that its $\ge$ a specific number) then the same "something" is true of every member of a subset of $A$.)

Therefore the greatest lower bound of $A$ is a lower bound of $A\cap B$.

Therefore the greatest lower bound of $A$ is less then or equal to the greatest lower bound of $A\cap B$.

$$
\inf A \le \inf (A\cap B).
$$

The same argument shows that $\inf B\le \inf(A\cap B)$.

If $\inf A$ and $\inf B$ are both $\le$ something, then $\max\{\inf A,\inf B\}\le$ that same thing.

Comment: what is max do?

Comment: If you're wondering what "$\max$" means, I wonder why you didn't ask about that in your initial posting.  If that's not what you meant, then I don't understand your question.